# Word for something that's worth remarking about

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm solving a problem that people face every day:

> Developers spend a **noticeable** amount of time writing this type of code.

Stating it's a "significant" problem seems too strong / an overstatement.

However, it's a problem I expect people to have experienced / be aware of.

Ironically, "remarkable" seems like the perfect word - i.e. it's a problem one might remark about - but this word inexplicably means "astounding" / "marvelous" (I don't know why that came to be...).

"Noticeable" and "comment worthy" seem like appropriate words/phrases.

Can anyone suggest other words?

Comment: Are you looking for a replacement for 'noticeable' in your sentence? I don't see anything remarkable that we can comment on and you haven't explicitly said why there is a problem. Perhaps a different sentence with a gap where the word should go would help.

Comment: What connotations will you add to "standard" or "well-known" ? Will **classic problem** fit ?

Comment: The problem is that there are hundreds of words that we could suggest.  We need it to be narrowed down.

Comment: I agree with chaslyfromUK it's a bit unclear what this question is asking. Are you looking for a word to describe the problem many programmers face or are you looking for a word to describe the solution to this problem. I upvoted CipherBot 's answer because I think noteworthy is a good term for the solution. However if you are looking to describe the problem I think tweaking Graffito's suggestion into "common problem" would be a good fit.

Comment: is there any reason not to use **remarkable**? "Worthy of attention; striking" seems apt plus it literally is from remark.

Comment: I don't know where you work, but the "P-word" (problem) is a big no-no, in a lot of organizations. Perhaps, if you are posing a solution, you could call it an ***"opportunity"***. (As many of us troubleshooters have learned to do.)

Comment: You could go for litotes:  *Developers spend a **not insignificant** amount of time...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Noteworthy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/noteworthy)

Worthy of notice or attention; notable; remarkable:

*A noteworthy addition to our collection of rare books.*

Comment: Down voter, why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 1):

If OP feels that ***significant*** is "too strong" for the context, it can easily be "tempered" by...

> *Developers spend [a **not insignificant** amount of time](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20not%20insignificant%20amount%20of%20time%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) writing this type of code.*

There are a claimed 94 written instances of the above usage in Google Books above, compared to over 2000 for [*a significant amount of time*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20significant%20amount%20of%20time%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). If a speaker avoids a far more common "direct" form, native speakers automatically assume there must be a reason - often, that the direct form carries "extreme" connotations that aren't appropriate for the specific context.

Answer (score 0):

"Marked" is often used in this context, to describe something that is noticeable without being extraordinary. "Distinct" has  similar meaning.

Answer (score 0):

nontrivial (that's mathematician-speak)

substantial (might be a bit too strong?)

considerable (again, might be too strong?)

goodly

decent (maybe a little too informal for your purposes?)

respectable (only works if you're feeling admiring and not resentful about the time spent)

fair

Answer (score -1):

*inordinate*, also, *longish*; *excessive*; *too much*;

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inordinate):

> 1 Unusually or disproportionately large; excessive
>   *She testified that the project was creating an **inordinate** amount of paper work, far in excess of the norm.*

Comment: I'd have to say that from *my* perspective, ***inordinate*** is far "stronger" than ***significant***, which OP has specifically ruled out as being excessive/overemphatic for his context.