# What is the opposite of a health benefit?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

I am looking to write an online article about the negative effects of eating/drinking a certain item.  There are articles that have a title such as "Top Health Benefits of _____".    What could be used to describe the *exact opposite*?

There is a similarly titled question, "[Antonym of benefit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269776/antonym-of-benefit)".  However, the content of the question is different and its answer is not helpful for my situation.

Comment: +1 for doing your research before posting! Would **detractions** work? A benefit is "an advantage or profit gained" while detraction is "a taking away". You'd end up with "Top Health Detractions of _____".

Comment: _Top health risks of_ might work.

Comment: Health _detriment_?

Comment: Health _malefit_?

Comment: @Crissov That is a pretty interesting answer.  I would take the time to add it as an answer.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson I had added it as an answer to the question you linked to, so repeated it here in a comment only.

Comment: @Crissov Never heard of it before, but its an awesome word and, given all-over-the-place suggestions below, it clearly fills an empty niche.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Top Health Risks** is the phrase that you're looking for!

[***Risk***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/risk) (noun)

> a situation involving exposure to danger.

[ODO]

For reference, here's an [Ngram plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=health+risks+of+alcohol&year_start=1975&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chealth%20risks%20of%20alcohol%3B%2Cc0) on the usage of "Health Risks of Alcohol" from 1975 to 2008.

Comment: I don't think the answer is this straightforward (I'm calling into question my own contribution., *threat*, too). A risk isn't necessarily bad for you. It's got to be actually detrimental to your health, 100% of the time, to be the opposite of a benefit, doesn't it?

Comment: @CharlE - At times, a **risk** in itself may not be bad, but when it is preceded by "health", it almost always means detrimental to health.

Comment: @CharlE "Health Risk" is different than a regular risk - it's taking on an activity that increases the chance of developing health complications - drinking heavily, smoking heavily, eating high fatty foods are all health risks - it's not a gamble to win something, it's saying that it's increasing your chances of getting those complications.

Comment: Whatever the literal meanings of all these words are, they words that most often are used as opposite pairs are 'benefits and risks'.

Comment: The logical opposite of *benefit* is not *risk*. A benefit has already materialized; a risk is only a potential. *Penalty*, *detriment* or *damage* are all logically better. @MItch: I'd say ["The Assessment of Risk and **Potential** Benefit"](https://bioethicsarchive.georgetown.edu/nbac/capacity/Assessment.htm) has it right. The opposite of *risk* is something like  *chance* or *opportunity*.

Comment: @Peter that is exactly what I'm saying. Standing alone, a benefit and a risk are not exact counterparts when taken literally. I'm just telling you that at least in medical practice, they are used together to signify the alternatives. Drug X does good things and bad things, they are called respectively benefits and risks. Life isn't literal.

Comment: that's (imho) because 'benefits' are intentional (i.e. if you take a drug, or adopt a health practice, it's to acquire the benefit), while risks are not (if you take the drug, or start the health practice, they may happen, but it's not why you take the drug and you hope they don't). also, in health, not much is ever guaranteed as far as i can tell, either benefits or risks.....

Answer (score 28):

You could consider using [**health hazard**](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/health+hazard) which means:

> A danger to health resulting from exposure to environmental
>   pollutants, such as asbestos or ionizing radiation, or to a life-style
>   choice, such as cigarette smoking or chemical abuse.

[Mosby's Medical Dictionary, 9th edition]

Comment: Hazard seems right to me.  A benefit offers to protect or provide for your well being.  A hazard threatens it.

Comment: I have the same objection as above: I find *hazard* not exactly opposing *benefit*. Rock climbing is a health *hazard*: You may not fall and walk away as well as you came. By contrast, seriously drinking comes with a health *penalty* (not only a potential).

Comment: @Peter You are comparing apples with oranges. You need to compare rock climbing with drinking and (rope-) free-climbing with serious drinking.

Answer (score 24):

How about **detriment**?

> 1. loss, damage, disadvantage, or injury.
> 2. a cause of loss or damage.

"Top Health Detriments of ________"

Comment: This is incorrect, because "the detriment of X" means that X is harmed, not that X is harmful.  "I drink lots of alcohol, to the detriment of my health."  You can see ngram results, that "detriment of" is now almost exclusively used in the construction "to the detriment of": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=detriment+of%2Cto+the+detriment+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdetriment%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20detriment%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 22):

I don't believe that there is a single word that fits exactly in that sentence structure "Health _____ of", but normally in medical circles things are either beneficial or harmful, so one would probably go for something like

```
"10 harmful effects of __________"
```

or

```
"10 ways ___________ can harm you"
```

or perhaps

```
"10 detrimental side-effects of__________"
```

although in today's world of over-senasionalizing things, for the tabloid-style title you'd go:

```
"10 ways ____________ can kill you!"
```

or

```
"10 ways ____________ will ruin your health!"
```

Comment: How about *ill effects?*

Comment: Number six will shock you!

Answer (score 14):

Consider,

***negative health effects***

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=425&bih=279&tbm=bks&q=%22negative+health+effects+of%22&oq=%22negative+health+effects+of%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...5994.22238.0.23087.45.36.3.0.0.0.512.7213.0j2j15j2j3j2.24.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..20.7.1700.NAMB3tQSayo)

[***damaging effects***](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/m%C3%A9fait)

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=509&bih=334&tbm=bks&q=%22damaging+effects+of%22&oq=%22damaging+effects+of%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...2497.14071.0.14384.38.30.0.0.0.0.452.4035.0j10j5j1j2.18.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..22.6.1318.0.POYHSGl2cWA)

***deleterious (health) effects***

> deleterious
>
> Having a harmful effect; injurious: *the deleterious effects of smoking.*
>   [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deleterious)
>
> Harmful often in a subtle or unexpected way *deleterious effects*; *deleterious to health* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deleterious)
>
> Injurious to health [Ramdom House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deleterious?o=O)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deleterious+effects+of+alcohol%2Cdamaging+effects+of+alcohol&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeleterious%20effects%20of%20alcohol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdamaging%20effects%20of%20alcohol%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4):

***Threats***, perhaps. *The Top Threats to Health from consuming _____*.

If you Google *Threats to Health* you will see that it is quite commonly used in the context you're suggesting.

> [Global public health threats in the 21st century](http://www.who.int/whr/2007/overview/en/index1.html)

from the World Health Organisation, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

[Disbenefits](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disbenefit?q=disbenefits) is a word I have used from time to time, though I was astonished to find that it doesn't appear in all dictionaries so may be office-speak, slang or new and is designated as 'British [English]' in the site linked in this answer

> Disbenefit
>
> **Noun**: A disadvantage or loss resulting from something:
>    ‘an environmental disbenefit to the area of Teesside’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

E.g. "The health ***disbenefits*** of eating [these things] are..."

Comment: Nice. I'm going to start using this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I live in the united states and have never heard of this word.  Too bad it is not common, as it seems to be the most logical word.

Comment: Double-plus good - i.e. horrible.

Comment: What next? Malefit?

Comment: Why have I received 3 DV? It IS a word, and an apposite one at that! Bemused.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of a health *benefit* is a **health penalty**. [Googling "health penalty" "health benefit"](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22health+penalty%22+%22health+benefit%22) comes up with quite a few significant links.

The word pair fits also etymologically quite nicely. *Penalty* as well as *benefit* are originally human acts: A punishment (Latin *poena*), and a good deed (*bene factum*). Both terms imply some sort of book keeping, as in in accounting or a game. Both terms  for originally human acts have acquired an impersonal meaning as well: ["The tax benefits of marriage"](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2015/02/tax-benefits-of-marriage/index.htm), or ["The Financial Penalty for LGBT Women"](http://www.thetaskforce.org/paying-unfair-price-financial-penalty-lgbt-women-america/). Using the term *penalty*, even when describing a consequence which is not the act of a single person, evokes an image of a rule based framework, like a sports game or a court case. Certainly some possibly imaginary score is lowered.

Both terms are frequently used in economics where they apply quite naturally, because it's a rule based framework where scores are kept.

Using them in medicine applies this concept of rule-based score keeping to a person's health and interactions, thus "economifying" or "gamifying" it.

Answer (score 1):

*Top Health **Malefits** of* ____

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/244660?redirectedFrom=malefit#eid) with prefix [mal+](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112684) ‘ill’, ‘wrong’, ‘improper(ly)’:

> Self-conscious use as an antithesis to *benefit* n.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malefit):

> *detriment, disadvantage, encumbrance, hindrance, nuisance, obstacle*
>   **Antonyms:** *advantage, aid, assistance, **benefit**, boon, foredeal, help*

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=malefit):

> Something that is harmful or disadvantageous.

Merriam-Webster has no entry for it, but upon search suggests [*malefic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malefic) ‘malignant’, ‘malicious’. The related actor term [*malefactor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malefactor), it lists of course.
So the word fits in well with other *mal+* terms, although some readers may mistake it to relate to *male* instead.

Other associations people may have are [Maleficent](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0027757/), the evil fairy in Disney’s 1959 adaptation of *Sleeping Beauty* and later installments of the franchise, and the board game [Malefiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malefiz) that is also known as Barricade.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "Top Health **Contraindication** of ...".

> Definition: medical reason for using something, such as a treatment,
> procedure, or activity. It implies risk.
>
> Example: *Quinia in small doses and stimulants are appropriate whenever there is no contraindication to their employment*.